# How to crop a Raster by Region?

Tags: raster, mapinfo, clip

I have created a grid using the point density function in VM. I would like to crop this image to a region created from buffering a polyline feature set. Is this possible? Alternatively I have used the set clip region tool, however this only hides the rest of the image where I would like to save the cropped region as a new layer/image.

Comment: Which version of Mapinfo are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using Vertical Mapper - which you stated was used to create the grid in the first place. Here is an exerpt from the Vertical Mapper 3.0 Help file:

"The outer margin of any grid file can be trimmed using a predefined polygon created in a Map window. This tool is particularly useful for trimming grid files to a standard map neatline. Only one grid file can be trimmed at a time.

Choose the region that represents the trimming edge.  In the Grid Manager, click the Tools button and choose the Trimmer command.  In the Save Trimmed Grid As dialogue, type a new file name for the trimmed grid in the File name box.  Once the .grd file is created, it appears in a Map window with a default colour palette applied. You can change the colour range assigned to the grid file. For more information, see Using colour in grids."

Alternatively, if you don't have access to Vertical Mapper any more then you can convert the VM GRD file into a MapInfo MIG file using the 'Grid Tools' utility from the Tool Manager, and then use the MIG Crop function available in the MIG Tools utility which can be downloaded here: [MIG Tools](http://www.hsgridder.com/downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

open layer control and make the top layer (cosmetic layer) editable.  Then once you've done the clip, use the save objects in cosmetic layer (I think it is called that).

Let me know how you get on

Comment: Thanks - Only issue here is that "Save cosmetic objects" is greyed out.. :/

Comment: It appears this is an elusive function in MI. Converting the grd to a MIG and using the trim function works but the MIG retains very little of the original values.

Comment: Have you made the cosmetic layer editable Will?

Go into the layer control, the cosmetic layer will be the one on the top, click the central check box and then try it...